# sap.ui.table.Table scrollbar does not reach bottom

Tags: sapui5

I've been working with sap.ui.table.Table for a while now but the scrollbar never reached the bottom. Fortunately I can see the last rows but it's still weird to not work as the samples...

Tried to study the samples which do not have the same problem and also the doc but nothing...

I do not have weird css on my table or components which shouldn't be used (table in the picture).

Version I'm using is 1.97

Sorry for the picture in the link but I'm still not allowed to insert it directly.

```
    var table = new sap.ui.table.Table({                                                                            
            extension: new sap.m.Toolbar({
                content:[
                    new sap.m.Button({
                        icon: "sap-icon://add",
                        text: "New"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Button({
                        icon: "sap-icon://delete",
                        text: "Delete"
                    })                  
                ],
            }),
            footer: new sap.m.Toolbar({
                design: sap.m.ToolbarDesign.Solid,
                content: [
                    new sap.m.ToolbarSpacer(),
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text:"entries"
                    })
                ]
            }),
            rows: { 
                path: "oModel>/users/result" 
            },
            selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
            visibleRowCount: 8,
            visibleRowCountMode: "Fixed",
            //rowHeight: 20})
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5zFS.png)

Comment: can you share some code ? It is hard to understand what is going on based on a picture

Comment: Thank you for answer. I just added some code which includes the properties of the table, unfortunately can't share more... For the content, I'm using only Inputs and Selects.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the guidelines? https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/grid-table/#behavior-and-interaction

> To prevent adverse side effects when scrolling vertically, all line items must have the same height (sap.ui.table.Table, property: rowHeight).

So maybe your rows don't match the rowHeight property. You can try to adjust it.

Also please make sure to only use supported controls inside the cells as listed here https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/grid-table/#Table%28ALV%29-CellContent

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I checked the guidelines. I'm using the supported controls and even tried to fix it with rowHeight but no luck...